# How to control the priority of individual feature labels in one layer?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a group of city in a small area with labels.
Due to label engine it shows them in a 'random order' (and certainly optimizing) according the space the have.

There is a way, **without duplicate the layer**, to prioritize just **ONE** city name to be show whatever the conditions are, the others showed cities order around doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional expression as you label:

```
CASE WHEN "MyCitynameColumn" = 'New York' THEN 
    MyCitynameColumn 
END
```

You can have more than one Case and combine with a Else statement:

Syntax

```
 CASE
    WHEN condition THEN result
    [ ...n ]
    [ ELSE result ]
 END
```

[ ] marks optional components

If you have a lot of small areas, resulting in too many cases, your better of using two layers for labeling.

Also you could add a column like Showlabel, fill it with 0 or 1, and use that in the expression

```
CASE WHEN "ShowLabel" = 1 THEN 
    "Vejnavn"
END
```

Or you can use an in function in a Case statement:

```
Case When "MyCitynameColumn" in ('Nibe','New York') then
    "MyCitynameColumn"
End
```

Comment: Thx, but I just want to prioritize a city, not hide the others. we will use different zoom level at the end (9 to 13).

Comment: Thx Jakob but my area is not a small one, it is Europe ;-). So we just need to manage some exeptions (only few). I understand perfectly your way. But in our case is not manageable.

Comment: It is not possibly to databind to the prioritize function. The closest I can think of is to databind a column to both ShowLabel and Always Show label under the rendering tab.

Comment: In previous mapping job I have done, I have used the duplicate layer, that you do not like, for jobs like this :)

Comment: We try to create an other style inside the layer and filtering the cities name we want in. We put this in higher layer order. But doesn't work. Maybe can be a trik in the labels function, but this out of our knowledge. So we made a turn around : we have an other layer for capital. So we downgrade those cities in capital order (OSM tag) then this work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this may be possible in `2.14` and above.

The **Priority** attribute in `Labels > Placement` allows you to `Edit...` an expression for the value. As in the picture below, it seems the `Priority` variable ranges from 0.0-10.0, and thus whatever expression you come up with should be in that same range.

[image]